# Oracle LOB Not getting stored inline

Tags: oracle, database-performance, clob

**Setup**

I have an oracle table that has couple of attributes and a CLOB datatype. The table below I have create with two ways ,each of which should give the same behavior.

```
CREATE TABLE DEMO(
a number (10, 2),
data CLOB
)

CREATE TABLE DEMO(
a number (10, 2),
data CLOB
) LOB (data) Stored AS (STORAGE IN ROW ENABLED)
```

**Scenario**

1. As per the oracle documentation when the CLOB is greater the 4000 bytes it will be stored outline else inline.
2. When I store the data in this table for a clob value say "Hello"  and then I see the segment information for the "Demo table" and "Demo table LOB segment" , it shows that all the data is going to table and no new blocks are being consumed in the Lob Segment.
3. When I store a bigger data with total character less than 1500 , then also I get the same behavior as above.
4. But when I store a data with total character > 2000 and < 3000 , then the LOB data is going to the LOB segment even though total character are less than 3000.

**Question**

1. Why is the data smaller than 3000 characters is going to the LOB Segment ? . Is that each character takes 2 bytes , which justifies that data till 1500 is going to the data instead of Log Segment.

**Problem**

Lots of disk space is getting wasted because of the LOB Table , since the CHUNK size is 8kb and the data per block will always be around 3 - 4K character and in some cases exceeding that.  So essential for each row 4Kb space is wasted and in out case of 20 mn rows , its running in 50's of GBs

Comment: Do you use UTF8? What characters do you store? If they are mostly non ASCII chars, 2000 characters may translate to more than 4000 bytes.

Comment: I am using UTF-8 characters only. Also I created a table with varchar2(4000) and tried to insert the same data that was stored outline. and the storage was successfull, which basically means that the total bytes are < 4000

Answer (score 2):

This may explain the above behaviour..

"The CLOB and NCLOB datatypes store up to 4 gigabytes of character data in the database. CLOBs store database character set data and NCLOBs store Unicode national character set data. For varying-width database character sets, **the CLOB value is stored in the database using the two-byte Unicode character set**, which has a fixed width. Oracle translates the stored Unicode value to the character set requested on the client or on the server, which can be fixed-width or varying width. When you insert data into a CLOB column using a varying-width character set, **Oracle converts the data into Unicode before storing it in the database."**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c13datyp.htm#3234